# How to check if an array exists in ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, listbox

How to check if an array exists in ListBox in C#

I have two **ListBox** populated from a database and I can move array items from **one listbox** to **another listbox** in asp.net using C#

Is there any way to check if a array exists or has a value?

I have this line of code but when I don't have values in the **second ListBox** populated from **first ListBox** the output is :

```
System.Collections.ArrayList
System.Collections.ArrayList


    ArrayList arraylist2 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arraylist4 = new ArrayList();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arraylist2.ToString() != "" && arraylist4.ToString() != "")
        {
            Response.Write(arraylist2.ToString() + "<br />" + arraylist4.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("not array values");
        }
    }
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

My code below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (arraylist2.Count > 0 && arraylist4.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(arraylist2.ToString() + "<br />" + arraylist4.ToString() + "<br />");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("not array values");
    }
}
```

**Edit#1**

```
if (arraylist2.Count > 0 && arraylist4.Count > 0)
{
    int b = arraylist2.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(arraylist2[i] + ", " + arraylist4[i]);
    }

}
else
{
    Response.Write("not array values");
}
```

**Edit#2**

```
arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.ToString());
arraylist4.Add(ListBox4.ToString());

b = arraylist2.Count;
c = arraylist4.Count;

if (b > 1 && c > 1)
{            
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(arraylist2[i].ToString() + ", " + arraylist4[i].ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("not array values");
}
```

**Edit#3**

```
arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.Text.ToString());
arraylist4.Add(ListBox4.Text.ToString());

b = arraylist2.Count;
c = arraylist4.Count;

if (b > 0 && c > 0)
{        
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(arraylist2[i].ToString() + ", " + arraylist4[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your Edit#2 your checking for the wrong number. If you have 1 item in both arraylists then you should be checking if b > 0 and c > 0.

Comment: Also, more importantly you need to iterate over the items in the listbox to add them to the arraylist. You can't just add the listbox to the arraylist like that.

Comment: @sr28: please see **Edit#3** in first question ... the output is empty ...

Comment: Please see my latest update. You need to iterate over the listbox items to add them to the arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both the lists `arraylist2` and `arraylist4` has something in it. As you are using `&&` in `if`, so both conditions must return `true`.

Below code worked for me -

```
  ArrayList arraylist2 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arraylist4 = new ArrayList();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arraylist2.Add("SomeVal");
        arraylist4.Add("SomeVal");
        if (arraylist2.Count > 0 && arraylist4.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(arraylist2.ToString() + "<br />" + arraylist4.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not array values");
        }   
    }
```

also

use

```
arraylist2.AddRange(ListBox2.Items);
arraylist4.AddRange(ListBox4.Items);
```

instead of

```
arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.Text.ToString());
arraylist4.Add(ListBox4.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: What "SomeVal" in my case?

Comment: assuming that your listboxes have values in it.. right?

Answer (score 1):

Converting arraylist2.ToString() doesnt make much sense. If you want convert a list to string you could do something like this:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 3 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (object o in arrayList) 
{ 
  sb.Append(o);
}
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: My problem is the check **arrayList count** ... not working ... I have always **"not array values"**

Comment: Maybe arraylist2.Count or arraylist4.Count is 0? How do you fill this lists?

Comment: Not ... arraylist2.Count is one and arraylist4.Count is one ... but the ouput is not array values ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what the problem is here, so focusing on your comment "Is there any way to check if a array exists or has a value?" you could use the ArrayList.Count property to determine if the arrays lists actually contain anything. So:

```
if(arraylist2.Count > 0 && arraylist4.Count > 0)
{
    //your code
}
```

If you want to display each item within the array lists you could loop through them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraylist2.Count; i++)
{   
    Response.Write(arraylist2[i].ToString() + ", " + arraylist4[i].ToString()) //or whatever you want to write.
}
```

This assumes the number of items are the same in each arraylist. If not then get the count of both lists and simply loop through the second list as well.

***EDIT***

As per my comment you would probably be better off changing your arraylists to List. So you could have something like this:

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add(//your values);
```

This would allow you to use the count property just like the arraylist but you should be able to simply show each item by using it's index (no ToString() needed).

***EDIT 2***

Ok, having seen your Edit#2 and Edit#3 you still aren't adding items from the listboxes to the arraylists properly. You need to add them like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < ListBox2.Items.Count; j++)
{
    if (!arraylist2.Contains(ListBox2.Items[j]))
    {
        arraylist2.Add(ListBox2.Items[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the Count or Any extension methods defined in System.Linq.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - updated. Sorry I was thinking of Array, not ArrayList. Now updated using ArrayList.Count (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.count(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Okay, please see **Edit** in my first question. I have always in output  **"not array values"**

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - I'm assuming you get this when you do arraylist2.ToString() and arraylist4.ToString(). That's because the ArrayList is a collection of items and can't just be displayed like this. You could loop through them though and display them.

Comment: @sr28: please see **Edit#1** in first question, the output is always **"not array values"** why?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - what's the type of the objects in the arraylists?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - why aren't you using List<T> instead of ArrayList?

Comment: @sr28: because I have tried this tutorial on the net: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-move-listitems-from-one-listbox.html

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq - there's no real reason to be using ArrayList instead of List<T> in this case. You'd be better off changing ArrayList to List<string>.